# Kotlin generics will not compile

Tags: kotlin

Been stuck on a problem for quite a while. This piece of code will not compile. I get an error on  line 4, `Type mismatch, found B require typeA` even though `B` is of `typeA`. I found a way to get around this by casting `B` to `typeA`, but this seems to be a horrible way(unchecked cast) to do it. Also changing the return type to `A<C>` would work too. I guess the smart cast is not smart enough?

```
class Test<typeA : A<C>> {

    fun returnB(): typeA {
        return B()
    }
}


open class A<c : C>

class B : A<C>()

open class C
```

Comment: FWIW, types (including type parameters) conventionally stay with a capital letter.

Comment: But the answer is that B is **not** of type typeA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is conceptually incorrect.

The declaration  `Test<typeA : A<C>>` means that `typeA` can assume one of the types that are subtypes of `A<C>`. It may or may not be `B`, and if it's not, `B()` is not a valid value to return. For example, you can declare another subtype of `A` and use `Test` with it:

```
class D : A<C>()

val testD = Test<D>()
val result = testD.returnB() // the result should be D, since testD has D for its typeA
```

The `fun returnB(): typeA`, then, should return a value of `typeA` for every possible `typeA`, not only for the case when it is `B`. The example above has `typeA` substituted by `D` and thus shows that returning `B` from `testD.returnB()` would be incorrect.